# Manipulating multi-indices for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multi-index. I have couple of questions on this.

The indices are week numbers (38 to 42) and for each week, day of the week (DOW). So it looks like

[image]

The problem is the 2nd level index, that is, DofWeek, is automatically sorted in lexicographic ordering. But I want to have the usual weekdays ordering, i,e for week 39, I want it to appear as Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thoursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday and NOT in the order they appear. So when I graph it, it appears this way:
[image]

I want it to appear in the usual Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc. I have tried reindexing, but it didn't work. This is my **first question**.

My **second question** is regarding querying such dataframes. For example when I do `dataframe.query('DofWeek == 'Saturday')`, it is throwing an error saying `Saturday is not defined`. However, if I swap levels and then query, it works. For example `dataframe.swaplevel().query('weekNum == 39')`, it works perfectly. As far as I know, the multi-indices should be sorted in order for certain methods to work. But in my case, they are. Then why isn't it working.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a heads up: you should only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ordering

You can achieve this by changing the datatype to [**ordered** categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#working-with-categories):

```
df['DofWeek'] = pd.Categorical(
                df['DofWeek'], 
                categories=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'], 
                ordered=True)
```

And then sorting the index:

```
df = df.sort_index()
```

---

### Error

The issue with `dataframe.query('DofWeek == 'Saturday')` is bad quote encapsulation. You could solve it with e.g. `'DofWeek == "Saturday"'`